# iPhone Mobile Safari: Portion of content scales by it self

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile-safari

Really, wondering and don't know why, on the initial load, the "<'p'>" element that holds content is scaled up, the fontsize, if i change orientation of the device it will then adjust scaling and keep it at declared font size that originally was intended, but that initial load. any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6652764/117290) and the answer that worked for me was:

> This is because sometimes Safari webview Zooms text automatically when
>   it thinks its a good idea.
>
> To disable this behavior add this to your body CSS Style:
>
> -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure loading CSS portion before content?

Comment: unless mobile safari loads head after body, i am pretty sure : )