# Weird behaviour when rotating iPhone for TDs with colspan

Tags: iphone, html, rotation, mobile-safari, html-table

This is about displaying a simple HTML page in iPhone's browser, with rotation.

**Setup**: two identical tables but one of them has a (CSS) width of 69% while the other is at 100%.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable = yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
    table
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th
    {
        font-weight: normal;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    td
    {
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
    #t1
    {
        width: 69%;
    }
    #t2
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="t1">
        <tr><th colspan="2">TH COLSPAN 2</th></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">TD COLSPAN 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>CELL 1</td><td>CELL 2</td></tr>
    </table>
    <hr />
    <table id="t2">
        <tr><th colspan="2">TH COLSPAN 2</th></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">TD COLSPAN 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>CELL 1</td><td>CELL 2</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Behaviour**: although the two tables are displayed with the same font size in the default orientation (portrait), when rotating the device the full width table displays TDs/THs having a COLSPAN=2 in a **bigger font size** (screenshots are taken from iPhone):

[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape]

This seems to be a bug in Safari but, nonetheless, I have to get around it.

Any idea about a decent workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because sometimes Safari webview Zooms text automatically when it thinks its a good idea.

To disable this behavior add this to your body CSS Style:

-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;

Comment: Yup, I just had the same problem two days ago and spent some hours figuring out how to solve this, so its nice to help others save research time. Also, this solutions works for UIWebView in iPhone natives Apps.

Comment: It has been a lifesaver